# How to use "all xs with value v for property p" as an object property range?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege, description-logic

I have a class , **Person**.  There is a datatype property **Profession** whose value for a **Person** are **{"Composer","Singer","Conductor"}**. I have another class that is called **Piece**, and an object  property **composedBy**.  I want the range of **composedBy** to be all **Persons** whose **Profession** is **"Composer"**? How can I do this in OWL, and how can I express that OWL using Protégé?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?  I added an answer that goes into a bit more detail about how you'd represent these axioms, and what it would look like in Protégé.

Answer (score 1):

Your first description isn't too hard to express as a DL axiom (although, I'll use the name *hasProfession* to be more consistent with the other property name, *composedBy*).

> There is a datatype property Profession whose value for a Person are {"Composer","Singer","Conductor"}.

> Person ⊑ Profession only {"Composer, "Singer", "Conductor"}

[image]

The second isn't too tricky either:

> I have another class that is called Piece, and an object property composedBy. I want the range of composedBy to be all Persons whose Profession is "Composer"?

Now, you need to be clearer here.  You might mean that the *range* of *composedBy* is "all Persons whose profession is ‘Composer’", i.e., that *anything* that is the value of a *composedBy* statement is a Peron whose profession is ‘Composer’.  However, you mentioned another class, Piece, so I think what you're asking is how to say that if a *Piece* is *composedBy* something, then that something is a Person whose profession is ‘Composer’.  That would be this axiom:

> Piece ⊑ ∀composedBy.(Person ⊓ hasProfession value "Composer")

[image]

If you want to copy and paste the ontology, here it is:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20920232/1281433/composers#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20920232/1281433/composers"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20920232/1281433/composers#Piece">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20920232/1281433/composers#composedBy"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:allValuesFrom>
          <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
              <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20920232/1281433/composers#Person"/>
              <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty>
                  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20920232/1281433/composers#hasProfession"/>
                </owl:onProperty>
                <owl:hasValue>Composer</owl:hasValue>
              </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
          </owl:Class>
        </owl:allValuesFrom>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20920232/1281433/composers#Person">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20920232/1281433/composers#hasProfession"/>
        <owl:allValuesFrom>
          <rdfs:Datatype>
            <owl:oneOf>
              <rdf:List>
                <rdf:first>Composer</rdf:first>
                <rdf:rest>
                  <rdf:List>
                    <rdf:first>Conductor</rdf:first>
                    <rdf:rest>
                      <rdf:List>
                        <rdf:first>Singer</rdf:first>
                        <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
                      </rdf:List>
                    </rdf:rest>
                  </rdf:List>
                </rdf:rest>
              </rdf:List>
            </owl:oneOf>
          </rdfs:Datatype>
        </owl:allValuesFrom>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the range for `composedBy` to be `Person and some Profession {Composer}`
What the range says is that the value of composedBy will be a Person and it will have a property Profession with possible values only Composer - it is a HasValue restriction.